# How to rewrite the Rebase file contents to change multiple commits

Tags: git, github

I was trying to use `git rebase -i` to improv my commits messages. I am the only one working on this director. By mistake, the file opened in the editor became like this:

```
noop

# Rebase d172428..d172428 onto d172428 (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified); use -c <commit> to reword the commit message
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

I aborted the rebase and tried to do it again, but the file opens with this same content. I tried to rewrite the original contents (like examples in tutorials) by adding my commits SHAs and messages. I ran `$ git rebase -i` and rewrote the content like the following:

```
pick d172428 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Add LCD Driver
pick cf6c9a2 Create README.md
pick 6c9286f Initial commit, first effort

# Rebase d172428..d172428 onto d172428 (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified); use -c <commit> to reword the commit message
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

But errors appear like:

```
interactive rebase in progress; onto d172428
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick d172428 Add LCD Driver
Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
   pick cf6c9a2 Create README.md
   pick 6c9286f Initial commit, first effort
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on 'd172428'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git rebase --skip'
Could not apply d172428... Add LCD Driver
```

I tried to change `pick` to `edit` for example. I tried skip, continue and abort. with the same problem. Each time I abort and try to rebase again the file starts with the same contnet `noob`.
How

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you also want to rebase all the way back to the first commit, you should be using:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

This should bring up the same screen you have been seeing:

```
pick d172428 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Add LCD Driver
pick cf6c9a2 Create README.md
pick 6c9286f Initial commit, first effort
```

As the instructions say, you may change `pick` to `reword` for all the commits listed:

```
reword d172428 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Add LCD Driver
reword cf6c9a2 Create README.md
reword 6c9286f Initial commit, first effort
```

Then press <kbd>ESC</kbd> followed by <kbd>:wq</kbd> to save and close.  This will start the rebase.  The rebase will reapply each of your commits from the root commit, allowing you to reword the commit message.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with the command. It looks like not passing `--root` means no commits are passed to the rebasing process. I thought that would rebase to the root.

Comment: @MohammedElbagoury Not exactly.  You typically will do something like `git rebase -i HEAD~5` e.g. to rebase the last 5 commits.  If you want to go all the way back to the root commit though, you need `git rebase -i --root`

Comment: And if I type `git rebase -i` without specifying a certain commit?

Comment: Not sure, you need to specify a base as an argument, and I have never tried using `git rebase` this way.

Comment: `git rebase` with no additional arguments means *look up the upstream setting for the current branch; if there is none, give me an error and quit; otherwise, use the upstream as the missing argument*.

Comment: The upstream for your `master` is apparently your `origin/master` (this is extremely normal), so you are in effect running `git rebase -i origin/master`. Since `origin/master` identifies the *same commit* that `master` identifies, you're directing Git to copy a list of commits that is empty (has no commits in the list). In the distant past (5 or so years ago) this produced an error; now it produces that `noop`.